# Grails Consuming JSON response.

Tags: ajax, grails

I'm trying to create a restful service and I'm trying to consume my JSON response and convert it back to an Object.

**Controller method**

```
def mergeVendors(String region) {

    def report = new VendorReport();
    //do something with  report

    response.status = 201
    response ([vendorReport: report]) as JSON
}
```

Test Method

```
void "Test Merge Vendors"() {
    when:       
    controller.request.method = 'POST'
    controller.request.json = '[{id:1, zip:"14224"}]'

    controller.mergeVendors("Florida")

    def response =  controller.response


    then:
    response.zip == "14224"
}
```

The code above is what I'm trying to use and I get the following exception. How do I cast the response back to a VendorReport obj?

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.healthresearch.VendorController.response() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[vendorReport:org.vendor.VendorReport@1b0dbdf1]]
Possible solutions: respond(java.lang.Object), getResponse(), respond(java.lang.Object, java.util.Map), respond(java.util.Map, java.lang.Object), respondsTo(java.lang.String), respondsTo(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;)

Answer (score 3):

```
response ([vendorReport: report]) as JSON
```

change to

```
render ([vendorReport: report]) as JSON
```

Comment: What do I need to do to cast the json back to a VendorReport object in my test?

Comment: `then: response.json == report`

Comment: then: 
    def response =  controller.response.json;
    response == report
Test Merge Vendors(org.VendorControllerIntegrationSpec)
 |
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Error parsing JSON
 at grails.converters.JSON.parse(JSON.java:278)
 at org.VendorControllerIntegrationSpec.Test Merge Vendors(VendorControllerIntegrationSpec.groovy:32)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or ']' at character 16 of ['vendorReport':org.vendor.VendorReport@1e5c61e6]
 at grails.converters.JSON.parse(JSON.java:269)
 ... 1 more

Comment: I don't know the structure of your VendorReport class. You might need a GSP template to generate proper JSON. Debug your app, check if your JSON is valid.